# Typescript error: Property '0' is missing in number[]

Tags: typescript

My class:

```
class Point{
  coordinates: [number, number, number];
    constructor(coordinates: [string, string, string]) {
    this.coordinates = coordinates.map((coordinate) => {
      return Math.round(parseFloat(coordinate) *100)/100;
    })
  }
}
```

The error I'm getting:

```
`Property '0' is missing in number[]`
```

[demo](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Point%7B%0D%0A%20%20coordinates%3A%20%5Bnumber%2C%20number%2C%20number%5D%3B%0D%0A%09constructor(coordinates%3A%20%5Bstring%2C%20string%2C%20string%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.coordinates%20%3D%20coordinates.map((coordinate)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Math.round(parseFloat(coordinate)%20*100)%2F100%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

What is wrong?

Comment: It works if `this.coordinates` is `Array<number>`.

Comment: _"What is wrong?"_ - what did your research show for that error? What do you want `coordinates` to be, a tuple or an array? What is the return type of `map()`?

Comment: @CodeCaster. Yeah a bit sloppy question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`coordinates` is a tuple type. In Typescript tuples inherit from arrays, and the methods available on tuples actually come from `Array<T>`. While this is useful, these methods return arrays nto tuples when called. So even though you call `map` on a tuple with 3 elements, and you would expect the result tu be a tuple with 3 elements, it will actually be an array.

The simplest solution is to use a type assertion to tell the compiler the result will be a tuple with 3 numbers:

```
this.coordinates = coordinates.map((coordinate) => {
    return Math.round(parseFloat(coordinate) * 100) / 100;
}) as [number, number, number];
```

**Edit**

Alternatively you can extend the `Array` global interface to correctly type the result of the `map` operation:

```
interface Array<T> {
    // up to 3 tuple items, you can add more
    map<U>(this: [T], callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U, thisArg?: any): [U];
    map<U>(this: [T, T], callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U, thisArg?: any): [U, U];
    map<U>(this: [T, T, T], callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U, thisArg?: any): [U, U, U];
}

class Point {
    coordinates: [number, number, number];
    constructor(coordinates: [string, string, string]) {
        // Will now work as expected
        this.coordinates = coordinates.map((coordinate) => {
            return Math.round(parseFloat(coordinate) * 100) / 100;
        });
    }
}
```

This GitHub [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6574) has an interesting discussion on the topic.